# Using argparse arguments from command line and from other scripts

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

```python
#projectname    
from projectname.source import foo
# Import about 10 more functions

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

    parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo', help="Help")
    parser_foo.add_argument("--bar", nargs="+", help='bar help')
    parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)

    # More subparsers for the other funtions

    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

#foo.py
def foo(args):
    print args
```

Usage: projectname foo [--bar]

Two questions:

1. I understand that command-line scripts should be run from `__main__.py` file, however, since the git-like style I'm using requires me to write the name of the file at the beginning, I dont know how to access `projectname` when the script runs from `__main__.py`. How can I make the first argument in the command line to be `projectname`?
2. I need my script to run directly from the command line and I also need to call these functions internally from another script. In this case I could use `projectname` at the beginning or not.

I could do this for each function:

```python
#foo.py
def foo(args):
    print args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
    parser_foo = subparsers.add_parser('foo', help="Help")
    parser_add.add_argument("--bar", nargs="+", help='bar help')
    parser_foo.set_defaults(func=foo)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    args.func(args)
```

But this means repeating each part for each function. I'm pretty stuck here!

Comment: By "calling functions from another script", do you mean calling python functions from other Python functions? If so, why would you even use argparse? Just pass the arguments directly.

Comment: @FlorianWinter I need to use the function ``foo`` mainly from another script. The reason why I use argparse is that I also need to be able to call them from the command-line directly.